# How to link build version to user story in Azure Dev Ops?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to link the build version number to user stories in Azure Dev Ops? I need this to make an effective release management system. I need to determine in real time if all user stories needed for the latest release have ben done. Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way in Azure DevOps to link build version number to User Stories.

Using REST API to update the work item with build version number could consider as a work around to your scenario.

Here is how I define the build number format in Azure Classic Pipeline.

[image]

Get the Work Item ID from UI

[image]

Use the Add Comment API as an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Add the below PowerShell script in your pipeline as a task.

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{workItemId}/comments?api-version=6.0-preview.3"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
   "text": "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

After each run, the "Build.BuildNumber" will be added as a comment in this User Story.

[image]

[image]